# android - simplify src path without hardcode

Tags: android, android.mk

I would like to remove the hardcode file path from Android.mk.

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),user)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := ./app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
else
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
endif
```

Maybe I can run a find command but not sure how can I get the user version with from release folder and userdebug version from debug folder.

Maybe something like below:

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     :=$(some command)

Comment: You haven't really told us much about your project, which makes it hard to answer your question. It's certainly possible to run shell command from within an `Android.mk` (look up  `$(shell)`). However, if you're building with Gradle, then it might be a better solution to determine the path from within your `build.gradle` and pass it as an argument when invoking `ndk-build`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := $(shell find -name '*.apk'|grep '$(FOLDER)/.*$(ARCH)')
```